# Accessing Navigation Property in Type Script

Tags: angularjs, typescript, asp.net-web-api

I have web api(/api/Category?includeProducts=true) which includes categories and products(navigation property) when called

```
export class Category {
    categoryID!: number;
    categoryName!: string;
    description!: string;
    picture!: any;
    products!: Product[];
}

export class Product {
        productID!: number;
        productName!: string;
        supplierID!: number;
        categoryID!: number;
}
```

when I call the api it fills the json data in this public categories: Category[] = [];

How can I fill  the products in   public products: Product[] = []; from categories property.

I have tried this code but it doesn't return

```
this.categories.forEach(function(element){(
  console.log(elements.products);
  )})
```

Edit: Data from the API

```
[
  {
"categoryID": 1,
"categoryName": "Beverages",
"description": "Soft drinks, coffees, teas, beers, and ales",
"products": [
  {
    "productID": 1,
    "productName": "Chai",
    "supplierID": 1,
    "categoryID": 1,
    "quatityPerUnit": null,
    "unitPrice": 18,
    "unitsInStock": 39,
    "unitsOnOrder": 0,
    "recordLevel": 0,
    "discontinued": false
  },
  {
    "productID": 2,
    "productName": "Chang",
    "supplierID": 1,
    "categoryID": 1,
    "quatityPerUnit": null,
    "unitPrice": 19,
    "unitsInStock": 17,
    "unitsOnOrder": 40,
    "recordLevel": 0,
    "discontinued": false
  },
```

}
]

The 's' was typo error sorry about that.

The data retrieved from api is being stored in `public categories: Category[] = [];`

Here is the HTTP Request `getData(): Observable<Category[]> { return this.http.get<Category[]>("/api/Category?includeProducts=true").pipe(retry(3), delay(3000)); }`

And here I am filling up the Categories where each category has multiple products inside

```
this.productstore.getData().subscribe(
        (data: Category[]) => {
            if (data == null) {
                this.statusmeassge = "No products found";
            }
            else {
                this.loading = false,
                    this.categories = data;
            }
        }, (error) => { console.log(error), this.loading = false });
```

I am trying to fill Product[] using like `this.categories.Products`

Comment: How is the data structured when it returns from the API? How did you build `this.categories`?

Comment: Also noticed that in your `forEach` loop you are calling `elements` with an `s`. Where you have defined the item as `element` without the `s`.

Comment: Could you share how you map the API result to the Categories?